# Means by rows and columns groups

Tags: r

How do I calculate the means of a variable per row for a column column?

For example if I have:

```
     x1    x2    x3    x4    x5   x6
1    93    97   216   220   98    98
2    78    70    NA    NA   77    83
3    88    89    NA    NA   86    93
4    77    71   198   211   85    78
```

I want to cacluate the of x1 and x2 for each row and the mean of x5 and x6 for each row.

My final data would look like:

```
     x1    x2    x3    x4    x5   x6  Meanx1x2   Meanx5x6
1    93    97   216   220   98    98      94.5        98
2    78    70    NA    NA   77    83      74          80 
3    88    89    NA    NA   86    93      ....
4    77    71   198   211   85    78
```

Comment: Try `rowMeans` `within(yourdata, {Meanx1x2<-rowMeans(cbind(x1,x2), na.rm=TRUE); Meanx5x6<-rowMeans(cbind(x5,x6), na.rm=TRUE)})`

Comment: `dat$Meanx1x2 <- rowMeans(dat[,c("x1","x2")])`, and similar for `Meanx5x6`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `?rowMeans`.

```
yourDataFrame$Meanx1x2 <- rowMeans(yourDataFrame[ ,1:2], na.rm = TRUE)
yourDataFrame$Meanx5x6 <- rowMeans(yourDataFrame[ ,5:6], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Similar useful functions include `rowSums`, `colSums`, and `colMeans`.

More complex operations that you want to apply row-wise can be accomplished using `apply` and setting the `MARGINS` argument to `1`.